# Unable to apply background color to a login box when a background image is used in the body tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background

On my login page, I have a background image attached to the body tag. On top of this image, I have a login box. But somehow I am not able to get a   background color to the login-box via class "bground_box" which i have applied to the div tag as shown below.

This is my css / html code.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .bground { background: url(images/bg-turquoise-waves.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover;  -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;}
  .bground_box { background-color:#25A8AF border: 3px solid white; border-radius: 25px; }
  .turqousie_text { color:#75F8FF;}
  .pgheight {  height:100%;  min-height:100%; }

</style>

<body class="bground">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <!-- Login Box -->
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bground_box">
    <h2 class="text-center turqousie_text"><strong>App Login</strong></h2><br/>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <form action="login.php" method="POST"  autocomplete="off" >
           <div class="form-group"><label for="uname"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> UserName</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Enter Your UserName">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group"><label for="upwd"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> UserPassword</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="upwd" name="upwd" placeholder="Enter Your Password"> 
           </div>  
           <button type="submit" name="login_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>               
     </form>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- end login box -->

</div> <!-- end  div row -->
</div> <!-- end  div container -->
</body>
```

Note - the solid white border appears nicely around the login box. That part works. Just CANT get a background color in the login box

Comment: Note - the solid white border appears nicely around the login box. That part works. Just CANT get a background color in the login box.

Answer (score 1):

is the problem occuring because you have 2 hashtags before the background color's hex value

Comment: Solved by using !important on .bground_box  background-color. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by using !important on .bground_box  background-color. This allows an override of the image background. Thanks.